Problem with EOF in C++ / Getting Runtime error
I have just started studying file handling in cpp
I am studying on my own from internet / and books
I Know about EOF (end of file) that indicates that this is the end of the file and its value is -1 i.e there is no more content left in the file.
we have a method in the ifstream class bool ifstream::eof() that return true if we have reached to end of file ,or false otherwise.
with this knowledge about eof i  constructed a program
that reads and write using read and write method of fstream class to the file.
Below is reading and writing minimal code that demonstrates what i am doing
class Book
{
  public:
    Book();
    Book(int _id, string _title, int price);

    bool storeBook(const string &) const
    {
        ofstream fout(fpath, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if (!fout)
        {
            -----
        }
        fout.write((char *)this, sizeof(*this));
        fout.close();
    }

    void setBook(int id, string title, int price)
    {
        .......
    }

  private:
    int id;
    string title;
    int price;
};

void readAllBooks(const string &fpath)
{
    Book b;
    ifstream fin(fpath, ios::binary | ios::in);

    if (!fin)
    {
        -------
    }
    while (fin.eof() == false)
    {
        fin.read((char *)&b, sizeof(b));
        if (!fin.eof())
            b.showBook();
    }

    fin.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** agrv)
{
    Book b1; 
    b1.setBook(11, "Agile Development", 200);
    b1.showBook(); 
    b1.storeBook("Data/books.dat");

    readAllBooks("Data/books.dat");

    return 0; 
}

Assume there is already some object of same type is stored  in the file.
expectation
I was expecting that this loop will break as soon as it finish reading all object from the file i.e when it reaches EOF
*what i am getting when reading all object by readAllBooks() method *
It is reading object one by one but at the end i am getting run time error of violation of access of memory location
What piece of information i am lacking with about eof or others that i am unable to figure out the cause of the error.
and i and getting this. Please guide me someone. Thanks for your time and guidance.

eof() does not return true if you have reached the end of file. eof() returns true after you have tried to read something and the read failed because the end of file was reached. That's a different thing. You check eof() after you have read something to find out why it failed, not before you read something to predict if it will fail.

However this has nothing to do with your crash. You cannot read std::string using read. Complex objects such as std::string (basically anything containing a pointer, that's a simplification though) cannot be read with read or written with write.

fout.write((char *)this, sizeof(*this)); does not do what you think it does. Start from here The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List

fin.read((char *)&b, sizeof(b));  Only works if book is trivially copyable which it isn't because it has a member std::string (which might allocate on the heap). So what you end up with is NOT what you saved.

Binary serialization is not trivial and best left to library developers. For now just save and load (serialize) in text format. The naive approach even if it works on your machine, can (will) break when compiler versions or settings change. Just do NOT do it like this

It also doesn't help a new programmer when garbage articles like this are posted on the web.
